# Как передать данные родительском классу через дочерний?

Tags: php, ооп, yii2, activerecord

Как передать данные родительском классу через дочерний?

Например в Yii2 есть класс `ActiveRecord` от которого я наследуюсь. Я переопределяю метод `tableName`, и возвращаю свой параметр. Он попадает в методы родительского класса. Как?

```
class Item extends ActiveRecord
{
   public static function tableName()
   {
    return 'item';
   }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обращаться в родительском классе к любым методам, определенным в наследниках. Ниже `Base::printProperty()` обращается к методу `property()`, который мы переопределяем в наследниках. Более того, мы можем потребовать, чтобы наследники определяли `property()` объявив его в базовом классе абстрактным (хотя это вовсе не обязательно).

```
abstract class Base {

  public function printProperty() {
    echo $this->property();
  }

  abstract function property();
}

class Child1 extends Base {
  public function property() {
    return 'Child1';
  }
}

class Child2 extends Base {
  public function property() {
    return 'Child2';
  }
}

$obj1 = new Child1();
echo $obj1->printProperty(); // Child1

$obj2 = new Child2();
echo $obj2->printProperty(); // Child2
```

Тоже самое сделано и в ActiveRecord только метод `tableName()` не абстрактный, а реализует логику по умолчанию.

```
class ActiveRecord extends BaseActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public static function tableName()
    {
       return '{{%' . Inflector::camel2id(
           StringHelper::basename(get_called_class()), '_') . '}}';
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!) то что нужно)

Comment: А как это все сделать используя только статические методы (объект класса создавать не надо)?

Comment: @Arzek точно также, только в определение функции добавьте ключевое слово static. В этом случае, да объекты вам не потребуются, а внутри функций вы не сможете обращаться к $this->